# why is this INTO statement not creating the new table?

Tags: sql

I have created the following dataset for testing/learning purposes:

```
numbers symbols colours
5   $   red
1   £   blue
32  !   green
84  *   yellow
16  %   
55  %   orange
```

The dataset is called test_dataset and is stored in Pre_Prod database. I want to create a new column based on the 'numbers' column and then create a new table with the 3 columns from test_dataset and the new derived column.

When i run the code the console outputs: (6 row(s) affected)

and the new table 'test_dataset_Deriv' is not in the Pre_Prod database. Is the code wrong?

```
select *,
case
when (numbers > 20) then 'over 20'
when (numbers < 21) then 'under 21'
end as 'numbers_range'

into Pre_Prod.dbo.test_dataset_Deriv
from Pre_Prod.dbo.test_dataset
```

Additional: I can view the columns in test_dataset by doing this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Pre_Prod.dbo.test_dataset
```

Thought i'd mention that just to show the test_dataset is where i'm saying.

Comment: Do you get any Error Messages?

Comment: I suppose this is MS SQL Server?

Comment: This works fine for me, maybe some issue with access rights? Did you try to do `SELECT * FROM Pre_Prod.dbo.test_dataset_Deriv` ?

Comment: How do you check whether `test_dataset_Deriv` was created?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and in standard SQL you need to use `CREATE TABLE .. AS SELECT...` to create a table based on a SELECT statement. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using